# Erro ao iniciar "Rails Server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá estou tentando instalar o Ruby on Rails no Ubuntu e ao startar o server utilizando o comando

```
rails server
```

me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
felipe@Dumont:~/mo$ rails server
/home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/mo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/mo/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/mo/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/felipe/mo/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /home/felipe/mo/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Alguém poderia me informar uma solução para este problema? sou usuário novato no Linux.

Comment: Cara eu também te aconselho usar o Nodejs: **sudo apt-get install nodejs**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro abra seu terminal e acessa a pasta do seu projeto e dá um `bundle install` ou instala a `gem install uglifier`. Fora que o rails precisa do NodeJs instalado na máquina para executar o motor javascript, com o comando `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Answer (score 1):

Certas ações que o Rails faz exige que um motor Javascript esteja instalado no sistema operacional. Isso inclui compilar arquivos [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) e [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), por exemplo.

- Tente instalar o [The Ruby Racer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) adicionando `gem "therubyracer", platforms: :ruby` no seu Gemfile e rode `bundle install`
- Se não funcionar tente instalar o [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/): `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: O recomendável é usar nodejs, the ruby racer tem uma série the problemas.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor opção é você instalar o nodejs mesmo! Já pra não ter esse problemas futuros!